# Textfiles with Forms and Multiple Outputs

Tags: c#, file, io, output

I  have a code that needs to take input for the weather of  certain day (and certain city) from the user and store that input into a textfile and then display that input for the specific cities from the textfile. I made use of FORMS.

How do I change my code to read the textfile correctly and NOT display each input 3 times each?
I added the relevant methods I made use of textfiles in:

```
  private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string city = cbCity.SelectedItem.ToString();
        DateTime date = dtp.Value;
        int minTemp = Convert.ToInt32(nudMinTemp.Value);
        int maxTemp = Convert.ToInt32(nudMaxTemp.Value);
        int precipitation = Convert.ToInt32(nudPrecip.Value);
        int humidity = Convert.ToInt32(nudHumid.Value);
        int windSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(nudWindSpeed.Value);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myFile.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(city + Environment.NewLine + date + 
                maxTemp + Environment.NewLine + precipitation...);
            sw.Close();
        }

        WeatherDetails w = new WeatherDetails(city, date, minTemp...)
        w.ReadData();
        MessageBox.Show("Your data has been Captured");
    }

   //Read data in WeatherDetails Class:
   public void ReadData()
    {

        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("myFile.txt");
        while (!SR.EndOfStream)
        {
            city = SR.ReadLine();
            date = DateTime.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
            minTemp = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
            maxTemp = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
            precipitation = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
            humidity = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
            windSpeed = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
            WeatherDetails newOne = new WeatherD...                      
            ci.Add(newOne);
        }
        SR.Close();
        }

  private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        city = cbCity.SelectedItem.ToString();
        DateStart = dtpStart.Value;
        DateEnd = dtpEnd.Value;

        //Displaying data to RTB
         private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        city = cbCity.SelectedItem.ToString();
        DateStart = dtpStart.Value;
        DateEnd = dtpEnd.Value;

        //Displaying data to RTB
        foreach (WeatherDetails wd in WeatherDetails.ci)
        {

            rtbDisplay.Text += ("The Weather Report for " +    cbCity.SelectedItem.ToString() + " , accesssed on " + wd.date.ToString() + "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "Maximum Temperature: " + wd.maxTemp + "\n" +
                "Minimum Temperature: " + wd.minTemp + "\n" +
                "Precipitation: " + wd.precipitation + "\n" +
                "Humidity: " + wd.humidity + "\n" +
                "Wind Speed: " + wd.windSpeed + "\n" +
                "-------------------End OF Report---------------------");
```

The issue is that it is displaying the entered data 3 TIMES each.So if i enter data for one city on the 12th and the 14th of May, it will display the 12th 3 times and display the 14th 3 times.

Comment: Did you look at the content of your file? There are three copy of the weather data or just one copy for each city?

Comment: The user enters the data into the file on the form, so the content is empty right now

Comment: I think you want to `Clear()` everything in `ci` everytime `ReadData()` runs.